# SearchBar becomes hidden when I navigate back

Tags: swift, tableview, issue-tracking

I have a SearchController inside my navigation bar, but I am facing problem when I push a UIViewController then get back, the searchbar becomes hidden.
Here is my code
[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1VQt.png)
[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EjLm.png)

I spotted some interesting stuff:

- When I set hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling to false it helps to solve that issue, but in this case I am not able to hide Search Bar when tableView is scrolling
- This issue appears only when I have table view

Comment: Try to provide some example code that reproduces your problem. Refers to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct to write more complete questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.